# Какой тип данных нужно использоватьв Python

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста есть такая структра

```
Компания |  Номер телефона 1

            Номер телефона 2

            Номер телефона 3

            Номер телефона 4

Компания2 | Номер телефона 1

            Номер телефона 2

            Номер телефона 3

            Номер телефона 4
```

Какой тип данных использовать в Python

Comment: В смысле какой тип данных? Любой... Например, словарь. В качестве ключа название компании, а в качестве значения список номеров: `{'Компания': ['Номер телефона 1']}`

Comment: В Python же есть классы. И списки. И словари. Можно просто словарь с ключом в виде строки и значением в виде списка использовать. Но без знания что вы дальше с этим всем хотите делать, сложно советовать.